# Regex that selects everything after first consecutive capitalized words

Tags: regex, drupal-7, drupal-feeds

I'd like to select everything after the first few consecutive capitalized words. ie:

```
Terry Smith is a good school teacher. She works tirelessly.
```

would become;

```
is a good school teacher. She works tirelessly.
```

So far this doesn't work work;

```
(^[A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)([\s\S]*)
```

I'm using it in Drupal's feeds tamper plugin with the "find replace regex" feature in order to replace everything after "Terry Smith" with blank space.

Comment: The regex of yours is basically fine, although the look-ahead part is redundant and can be omitted. The real question is how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression with match all consecutive capitalized words at the beginning of the sentence.

```
^(?:(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)(?>\s*))+
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lD9vQ4)

If you want to remove that part from the setnence then all you have to do is replace it with the empty string.

If you want to replace the part that comes after it then you can use the following expression:

```
^((?:(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)(?>\s*))+)([\s\S]+)
```

and use a replacement string of `$1` or whatever in your language that is used to reference the first captured group.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fY0vI4)

Answer (score 0):

This will find the capital words:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+(?=\b)\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You might want to replace the `+` with `*` after `[a-z]` to also match single-character capital words.

To get all capitalized words at the beginning of the string, add `^(` and `)+` around it:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]+(?=\b)\s*)+
```